# conf file for spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot

i am running spring boot application as services in Linux distribution . Usually i do a symbolic link for the fat jar and create the service pointing to a symbolic link file

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 152 Apr 19 13:53 bootstrap.yml
-rwxr--r-- 1 root root 59M Apr 11 12:39 common-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  17 Apr 24 10:55 common-service.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  33 Apr 10 09:42 common-service.jar -> common-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Now when i start the service it does not recognize `common-service.conf` but if i change the name to `common-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.conf` it does work perfectly

So is their a way to make spring boot read config file using the symbolic link file name instead of the actual file name

Comment: According to https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html there's nothing standard that looks for a `*.conf` file -- so you'll need to find out what you've done to make it find that. Or do something standard.

Comment: Apologies, .conf file is documented here - it's unique to the embedded launch script. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html#deployment-script-customization-conf-file

Comment: Are all these files in `/etc/init.d/common-service` ?  I think you need to avoid having the file with the versioned name in that directory, because the `init.d` service will find it and try to start it that way.

Comment: no , I do have a folder under `/usr/share/xxxxx/` . I have a symbolic link from `/etc/init.d/common-service  -> /usr/share/xxxx/common-service.jar` which also forward to the actual version i want . checking [launch.script](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-loader-tools/src/main/resources/org/springframework/boot/loader/tools/launch.script) I see that before setting `configfile`  `jarfile`  is changed to its real name . in my case i need the opposite

Comment: Better change the question to accurately state what you have in which directories. I see the problem - the embedded script uses `readlink` to dereference the link then expects to find a `.conf` for this. I don't have a better answer than customising the script.

Comment: thanks @slim this is what i think also , i will try to do a PR to support both instead of only actual name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did update the launch.script in spring boot as in this [PR](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/8988/files) .

basically what i did is i saved the original file name

```
originalconfigfile="$(basename "${jarfile%.*}.conf")"
```

and then if a conf file do exist with originalconfigfile use it if not check the real one

```
[[ -r "${CONF_FOLDER}/${originalconfigfile}" ]] && source "${CONF_FOLDER}/${originalconfigfile}"
[[ ! -r "${CONF_FOLDER}/${originalconfigfile}" ]] && [[ -r "${CONF_FOLDER}/${configfile}" ]] && source "${CONF_FOLDER}/${configfile}"
```

then I used this updated script in pom

```
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                    <embeddedLaunchScript>launch.script</embeddedLaunchScript>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build-info</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: Sorry to dig this up after 2 years, but looking at the PR it seems the behaviour requested by the OP was not implemented in the end?